# I try to grep date in a file and not work

Tags: grep, sh

The file is like this:

```
20180203235900 DEFAULT, Proc_m0_s1 
20180203235900 DEFAULT, Proc_m0_s17
20180203235900 DEFAULT, Proc_m0_s19
20180203235900 DEFAULT, Proc_m0_s3
20180203235900 DEFAULT, Proc_m0_s5 
20180203235900 DEFAULT, Proc_m0_s7 
20180203235900 DEFAULT, Proc_m1_s11
20180203235900 DEFAULT, Proc_m1_s13
20180204200000 DEFAULT, Proc_m0_s1
20180204200000 DEFAULT, Proc_m0_s17
20180204200000 DEFAULT, Proc_m0_s19
20180204200000 DEFAULT, Proc_m0_s3 
20180204200000 DEFAULT, Proc_m0_s5 
20180204200000 DEFAULT, Proc_m0_s7 
20180204200000 DEFAULT, Proc_m1_s11
20180204200000 DEFAULT, Proc_m1_s13
```

I am using

```
DATE=`eval date +%Y%m%d`
grep -e $DATE* -e DEFAULT* file.txt > fileoutput.txt
```

Comment: So, you only want the dates? For example, for the first row it should output only `20180203`?

Comment: This is 2 merge file starting at 19:00 and end at 19:00 I only need from one day starting at 00:00 and end 23:59 is collected every 5 minute. This is a reason to get only current DATE* with the wilcard

Answer (score 1):

1. You don’t need `eval` here, because the backticks already evaluate the expression they enclose.
2. If you want to pass an expression with asterisks to a command like `grep`, you must quote the expression (e.g. `grep -r "$DATE*" …`). Remember to use double quotes if you want the variable to be interpreted.
3. Actually, you don’t need to asterisks at all in this case, because grep should match anyway.

What should work for you is:

```
mydate=$(date +%Y%m%d)
grep -e $mydate -e DEFAULT file.txt > fileoutput.txt
```

(Note: I prefer to spell local variables with lowercase letters, and I use `$()` instead of backticks because of readability.)

Comment: Each line contains `DEFAULT` so `cp file.txt fileoutput.txt` is also possible.

Comment: @Cyrus: True, didn’t think about that. :)